# MySQL, разделить SELECT на лимиты

Tags: mysql, любой-язык

Задача: Eсть родительский процесс который ставит задачи, то есть говорит что нужно обработать 1000 и оправляет это дочернему процессу который уже занимается обработкой, одновременно может работать до 10 дочерних процессов, после отработки дочерний процесс умирает и за место него появляется новый, длится до тех пор пока все записи не будут обработаны.

---

Есть необходимость обойти асинхронно 200 тысяч записей и после обработки 1 записи изменить ключ что запись уже была обработана.

На данный момент все записи обрабатываются кусками по 2000 записей.

> Использую в примере псевдо язык программирования что-бы не грузить лишним кодом, но на бою использую `php`, но также задача есть и для `Python`

То есть получаеться такой код:

```
count = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM purchas WHERE status = 0;"

step = 2000
max = step

for (min = 1; min < count; min+=step) {
    // Дальше идет асинхронный код
    while(row = "SELECT * FROM purchas WHERE status = 0 LIMIT $min, $max;"){
        "UPDATE purchas SET status = 1 WHERE id = $row['id'];"
    }
}
```

Но логично обход буден не последовательный из-за того что вы меняет `status` и вопрос как можно это реализовать методами SQL?

> Возможно я не корректно задал вопрос.

Comment: А какой смысл статус 0 менять опять на 0 ? И зачем вам лимиты нужны (лимиты в таком виде дико тормозят работу, потому как БД что бы достичь записи $min надо все равно прочитать все предыдущие и выбросить). Да и результат работы у вас не предсказуем. При update запись может переписываться в другой блок данных и при этом физический порядок записей на диске изменится и при следующей попытки выборки пропуск $min записей уже не будет иметь смысла потому как могут быть пропущены совершенно не те строки, которые были обработаны на первой итерации. Короче, опишите подробно задачу, ее надо решать иначе

Comment: status как был нулём, так и остался, где-то опечатка?

Comment: Какую работу с записями вы выполняете, ее точно нельзя выполнить одним запросом хотя бы для блока данных ?

Comment: @Mike да, ошибка со статусом, он изменяется на 1, проблема в том что на VPS не хватает ОЗУ что-бы держать в памяти столько записей, да и еще есть подобная задача где речь идет уже об 8 миллионах

Comment: А зачем вам тогда вообще получать count(). считать сдвиги и т.п. выполняйте в цикле запрос `select * from tab where status=0 limit 2000`, обрабатывайте свои 2000 записей, меняйте статус. И повторяйте запрос опять, вы же статус поменяли, значит обработанные строки в выборку больше не попадут. И цикл делаете до тех пор пока запрос возвращает строки. Если вернул 0 строк - значит все обработано

Comment: @Mike постарался описал задачу, проблема в том что обработкой занимаются сразу 10 дочерних процессов. Хотя возможно все намного проще и Limit 2000 подойдет.

Comment: Если закономерностей в выдаче id нет. вернее если нет закономерностей, что по какой то причине например четных id в несколько раз больше чем не четных, то обработчики могут брать гарантированно не пересекающиеся наборы строк, например беря записи с остатком от деления id на количество обработчиков равным номеру обработчика. `where status=0 and mod(id,10)=N limit 2000`

Comment: @Mike а отличный вариант, правда нужно отслеживать какие ключи свободны. Спасибо за ответ.